# Why reading a compressed TAR file in reverse order is 100x slower?

Tags: python, performance, tar

First, let's generate a compressed `tar` archive:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from tarfile import TarInfo
import tarfile

with tarfile.open('foo.tgz', mode='w:gz') as archive:
    for file_name in range(1000):
        file_info = TarInfo(str(file_name))
        file_info.size = 100_000
        archive.addfile(file_info, fileobj=BytesIO(b'a' * 100_000))
```

Now, if I read the archive contents in natural order:

```py
import tarfile

with tarfile.open('foo.tgz') as archive:
    for file_name in archive.getnames():
        archive.extractfile(file_name).read()
```

and measure the execution time using the `time` command, I get less than **1 second** on my PC:

```
real    0m0.591s
user    0m0.560s
sys     0m0.011s
```

But if I read the archive contents in reverse order:

```py
import tarfile

with tarfile.open('foo.tgz') as archive:
    for file_name in reversed(archive.getnames()):
        archive.extractfile(file_name).read()
```

the execution time is now around **120 seconds**:

```
real    2m3.050s
user    2m0.910s
sys     0m0.059s
```

**Why is that?** Is there some bug in my code? Or is it some `tar`'s feature? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: tripleee's answer lays down the facts, and the documentation really [is the file format documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html)...

Comment: `tar` means `tape archive`. Think about what happens when you do the same with a tape in the early days of computing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `tar` file is strictly sequential. You end up reading the beginning of the file 1000 times, rewinding between them, reading the second member 999 times, etc etc.

Remember, the "tape archive" format was designed at a time when unidirectional tape reels on big spindles was the hardware they used. Having an index would only have wasted space on the tape, as you would literally have to read every byte between where you are and where you want to seek to on the tape anyway.

In contrast, modern archive formats like `.zip` are designed for use on properly seekable devices, and typically contain an index which lets you quickly move to the position where a specific archive member can be found.

Comment: And this is compounded by the fact the file is compressed; there's no way to seek to an exact uncompressed byte offset in a compressed file (and you need to seek in order to find the data to pull out from the archive).

Comment: @AKX Yes, reading an uncompressed archive seems to be fast in both ways.

Comment: In fairness, @tripleee, if you have an uncompressed .tar and you've read through all the entry metadata once, you can quickly move around too. On the other hand, with ZIP files (and I wouldn't call a 34-year-old format modern), you need to always rewrite the central directory after you append data, which you don't need to do with tar files.

Comment: (Agree; I use "modern" advisedly.)

Comment: Just FYI, and you already have my vote... you don't actually have to read every byte of a physical tape to seek to a new position. Many tape drives support *"tape marks"* and you can tell a drive to seek forward/backwards by N tape marks and it positions remarkably quickly.

Comment: Surely this must be a newer invention than the mid-1970s though? (I tried to Duck Duck Go but all the hits I could find were about measuring tape.)

Comment: You can use `mt -f /dev/st0 fsf 3` to move forward 3 files https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/managing_storage_devices/managing-tape-devices_managing-storage-devices#tape-commands_managing-tape-devices and see section **IOCTLS** here https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/scsi/st.html

Comment: @Jeyekomon *"reading an uncompressed archive seems to be fast in both ways"* - So you're saying this answer is wrong.

Comment: Or maybe that the Python `tarfile` library does some indexing of its own when the file isn't compressed ...?

Comment: I think it *does* some "indexing", yes. In the sense of storing the offsets of the archive members inside the archive. But for both uncompressed and compressed. And when you read one member, it doesn't necessarily read all previous, instead it seeks to the member's offset. Which I think is only slow because of what @AKX pointed out.